# Hartshorne- Algebraic Geometry, Exercise 1.3.15

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, affine-varieties

Part c) of this question asks you to prove that the product of affine varieties is a categorical product.

I am having trouble in proving the mediator from an arbitrary $Z \rightarrow X \times Y$ is in fact a morphism.

I feel like the fact that $Z$ has the Zariski Topology means that it's large enough to be able to guarantee that this map is continuous but I can't see how to reduce a closed (or open) set $V \subset X \times Y, V = Z(a)$ for some ideal $a \subset k[x_1,...,x_{n+m}]$ into parts where I can use the continuity of the given maps $Z \rightarrow X , Z \rightarrow Y$.

I'm also not sure about how to prove the regular bit too but I feel it should come a lot easier once I can get the continuity bit and see how the open/closed sets are supposed to split up.

Comment: A product in the category of affine schemes, or a product in the category of all schemes? Or a product in some other category?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It says the 'category of varieties', and the rest of this section in the book deals with that category which includes any affine, quasi-affine, projective or quasi-projective variety over a fixed algebraically closed field $k$.

Comment: So is this before Hartshorne introduces schemes?

Comment: Yes schemes are in chatper 2, this is in chapter 1 section 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** One possibility is to use part Lemma 3.6 or part $(b)$ of the exercise (the natural isomorphism between $A(X)\otimes_k A(Y)$ and $A(X\times Y)$) and Proposition 3.5.

**Added later:**
Since there have been some uncertainties concerning the arguments used in the comments, let me sketch what was said there, with some extra care where we are abusing notation. For simplicity, assume $X = \mathbb{A}^n$ and $Y = \mathbb{A}^m$ with coordinate rings $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $k[y_1,\dots,y_m]$; the exercise constructs(!) $\mathbb{A}^n\times\mathbb{A}^m$ as $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$ with coordinate ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m]$ by slight abuse of notation (in fact, the global coordinate function represented by $x_i$ on $X\times Y$ is secretly the regular map $x_i\circ p_1$ and likewise for the coordinates $y_i$).
Thus, Lemma 3.6 implies that a map $\phi\colon Z\to X\times Y$ is a morphism if and only if all the maps $x_i\circ p_1\circ \phi$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$, and $y_i\circ p_2\circ \phi$, $i=1,2,\dots,m$, are regular functions. Applying Lemma 3.6 again, this is seen to be the case if and only if $p_1\circ \phi\colon Z\to X$ and $p_2\circ \phi\colon Z\to Y$ are morphisms, and this is exactly what we have to show.

Comment: Ah tyvm using Lemma 3.6 helped a lot. However there is a subtlety I am hung up a bit on- call the mediator $\phi : Z \rightarrow X \times Y$ and suppose we are trying to show that $f \circ \phi$ is continuous for any polynomial $f \in k[x_1,...,x_{n+m}]$.

The lemma allows us to just show this for $x_i \circ \phi$ and then since this map which goes from $Z$ to $X \times Y$ to $k$ is the same as the map which goes from $Z$ to $X$ to $k$ (for $1 \leq i \leq n$) etc. which we know is continuous.

Comment: But for arbitrary $f$, $f \circ \phi$ doesn't go through $X$ or $Y$ but since it is an addition or multiplication of continuous functions it is continuous anyway?

Is that what is going on here?

Comment: Your first comment seems fine. I'm not sure I understand the questions of your second comment. By the way, perhaps I should have added Proposition 3.5 to the list of statements you might want to use, but I think it can be done with Lemma 3.6 only if you really want to.

Comment: I think I managed it with just Lemma 3.6 (didn't use part b) of the question).
My second comment is just something which to me doesn't feel correct, but I think it is true (if my proof is to be correct). If we take $f= x_1 + x_{n+1}$ then this f isn't a polynomial over either of $k[x_1,...x_n]$ or $k[x_{n+1},...x_{n+m}]$, but when showing that $x_i \circ \phi$ is continuous we view $x_i$ as a polynomial in $k[x_1,...x_n]$ as opposed to $k[x_1,...x_{n+m}]$.
We seem to be able to skip out this issue using the Lemma and I'm not fully convinced it is correct to do so.

Comment: Indeed, this implicitly uses that $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$ is the categorical product $\mathbb{A}^n\times \mathbb{A}^m$.

Comment: Could you expand further on that comment? How does it being the categorical product resolve the issue? Also do you have a reference for this fact or can it just be shown by mapping into the category of finitely generated IDs over $k$?

Comment: You can ignore that comment; that's one way to think of it, but we can do without it: we want to show that the composition $Z\xrightarrow{\phi}X\times Y\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n+m}\xrightarrow{x_i}\mathbb{A}^1$ is a regular function and (if $1\leq i\leq n$, say) we rewrite this map as the composition $Z\xrightarrow{\phi_1}X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n}\xrightarrow{x_i}\mathbb{A}^1$ of which we already know it's regular. (To be continued...)

Comment: (Continued...) The point is that the map(!) $x_i\colon \mathbb{A}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{A}^1$ factors through the projection map $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{A}^n$ and since we're talking about maps of sets here, we don't really have to care whether the projection is a morphism or not and whether or not it has any categorical properties or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64244/discussion-between-fromage-and-ben).